# how to throw errors in a closure in swift?

Tags: ios, error-handling, closures, swift2

Please look at the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

   let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: {
        (action : UITableViewRowAction, indexPath : NSIndexPath)  -> Void  in

        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext{
            let restaurantToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Restaurant
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(restaurantToDelete)

            // Saving managedObjectContext instance, and catch errors if it fails
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }

    })
    return deleteAction
}
```

the error message from Xcode is : Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void'

I know the problem is managedObjectContext.save() will throw errors and this is not allowed in the completion handler. I found some blog articles where they modified the closure parameters in order to make the error handling in a closure workable. While here the definition of the function is given by apple, so how can i fix this issue? Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the compiler is adding `throws` to the signature of your block because your `catch` clause is not exhaustive: the pattern match `let error as NSError` can fail... see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID512)

the signature of the closure argument is `(UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void`, however the compiler is inferring the type of the closure that you are providing to be `(UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) throws -> Void`

by adding another `catch` clause (with no pattern) after the one you already have the compiler will see that you are catching the exception locally and it will no longer infer that the signature of the closure you are providing includes `throws`:

```
do {
  try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
} catch {}
```

Comment: @user3788747 give this a shot and report back please!

Comment: yes,  you are right ! Thank you very much! but i still can not understand the reason behind. Thank you again!

Comment: @user3788747 excellent! answer updated with a more detailed explanation (and a link to the documentation), ready for your acceptance - happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Not possible, because the closure can be invoked at any time, probably not at execution time of your function, so where should the error propagate to?

You have to call out to another function which can handle the error:

```
func handleError(error: ErrorType) {
    switch error {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then call this function with your caught error inside the closure